# When sharing archived app via email, why does Xcode attach both the ipa and the mobileprovision?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, ipa

In Xcode:
Window->Organizer
Share...->Save to Disk...

You get an ipa.

Share...->Email...

You get an ipa and a mobileprovision file as attachments. But is seems that the very same mobileprovision is included in the ipa as well. Why the out-of-band mobileprovision? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a checksum on the mobileprovision file inside the IPA and the one outside, you'll notice that they don't match.  Your beta users will need the one that is not packaged inside the IPA.  I can only speculate on the need for the one inside the app bundle, but perhaps it used in the identification process in conjunction with the one outside.

Comment: Hmm. If you do Share->Save to Disk... is that IPA different? I do that all the time, and I am able to install the IPA over the air all the time w/out trouble. The mobileprovision file is of the PKCS#7 format. Good tip that the two are different...

Comment: The mobileprovision file is only needed once for a particular device.  It basically just serves to authorize the device, in the absence of XCode.  Any future IPA files, even for entirely new projects can be deployed to an "authorized" device until the authorization expires, or you replace the provisioning file in XCode.